# Cannot find option of datalist with `@testing-library/cypress`

Tags: cypress, wai-aria, html-datalist, testing-library, cypress-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test that confirms that a `<datalist/>` has a list of `<option/>` elements using role-based queries from `@testing-library/cypress`. Strangely, when I try to query by the `option` role:

```js
cy.findByRole('option')
```

...I get back no results:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option"

...despite the content appearing in the page:

```html
<datalist id="subjects-list">
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
</datalist>
<input list="subjects-list" value=""/>
```

Is there a way to find these options with `@testing-library/cypress`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key seems to be using `hidden:true` option (from the message received in Cypress).

If you apply that option, the test finds both `<option>`s but then complains that there are multiple results, so you then need to switch to the `*All` version.

```js
cy.findAllByRole('option', { hidden: true })
  .eq(0)
  .should('have.value', 'one')
```

That's the mechanics of it, the why of it is slightly more mysterious.

This is what the docs say about the `hidden` option

> If you set `hidden` to `true` elements that are normally excluded from the accessibility tree are considered for the query as well.

I think `<datalist>` is by default hidden, for example here [`<datalist>`: The HTML Data List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) the sample page does not show the options until you click into the `<input>`.